# How to download part of file from Google Storage

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I use Google Storage API for C# and not found how to download part of file from Google Storage.
Is it possible?

That is my code:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ObjectsResource.GetRequest request = _service.Objects.Get(bucketName, fileName);
    request.MediaDownloader.ChunkSize = chunkSize;
    request.Download(stream);
}
```

Comment: If the Google Storage API does not allow to do this, you could always design your own stream. You'd accept the first X bytes and drop the next ones (granted, that wouldn't stop the download) or throw a custom exception (which should stop the download).

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download#sample-code) it should work. Do you encounter any errors or problems?

Comment: For example I have very big file, and I want to read end part of this file at the some offset. I not found in documentation how to do it.

Comment: API-wise, yes, GCS fully supports standard HTTP range headers. I'm not entirely sure how to get the C# client to do it, though.

Comment: One note about range GETs - you don't get checksums for partial content, so doing a range GET leaves you less protected from client/library bugs that might corrupt your content.

Comment: Reading the docs, I don't see a way to do this.  I filed an issue on the git repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this with the .NET Google Cloud Storage SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/ on nuget):

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetObjectData(string objectKey, long startByte, long endByte)
{
    var options = new DownloadObjectOptions
    {
        /* chunk byte size - 1 because byte offset starts at 0, the end range byte is inclusive: 1000 would request 1001 bytes
         * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests */
        Range = new RangeHeaderValue(startByte, endByte - 1)
    };

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await storageClient.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, objectKey, memoryStream, options);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```